# Substring matching in string

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find and replace value in column string by using another column.

I have two columns labels and choice.

```
Table 1
id = 12
labels = case1|case2|case3

table 2
id =12
label&values = case1coke.case2fanta:case3cheez
```

The above example is in english but label&values and labels column are in Japanese. I tried to use `regex_replace` but due to volume of data and many special case character regex_replace not working for me. I am looking an approach where we can solve my problem by string matching

Expected output is:

```
id  label   value
12  case1   coke
12  case2   fanta
12  case3   juice

df = sqlContext.sql("select \
a.shop_id \
,a.item_id \
,regexp_replace \
    ( \
        regexp_replace \
            ( \
            a.choice \
            ,concat('(^|(?<![:：]))(', concatlables, ')') -- this is not working for all of the japanese records in this case \ 
            ,'⚙$2⚛' \
            ) \
    ,'⚛[:：]' ,'⚛' \
    ) as choice \
from \
rdsp_production_production_ex_odin_mall.basket_main2 a \
inner join brandmart.control_labels_concatlabels b \
on a.shop_id = b.shop_id \
and a.item_id = b.item_id \
where a.reg_date > '2019-02-07'")

r = df.select("shop_id","item_id",f.split("choice", "⚙").alias("final"),f.posexplode(f.split("choice", "⚙")).alias("pos", "val"))
split_col = split(r['choice'], '⚛')
r = r.withColumn('NAME1', split_col.getItem(0))
r = r.withColumn('NAME2', split_col.getItem(1)
```

> Error
>   error [Stage 23:> (6 + 2) / 2977]19/02/14 11:45:58 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 972.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 54, bhdp4411.prod.hnd1.bdd.local, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 79 (^|(?

Comment: id label and values are columns and their values are [12, case 1, coke] ,[12, case 2, fanta] and [12,case 3, juice]

Comment: Show your code and error

Comment: Try also to not add fundamental explanations in the comments - add them in the question. Maybe, in your case, draw the columns and respective values for each table

Comment: In case your problem becomes japanese specific, there is a japanese version of stack overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682651/regexp-replace-failed-on-some-records-in-pyspark

I have placed the exact problem and code on above link